# Compare column with multiple values in a specific order

Tags: sql-server

I need to compare a column with multiple values but in a specific order.

For eg: If values are AA, BB, CC, DD.

Than my query should be such that it compares AA to column first and than BB, CC and DD.

Here is my query assuming that CASE WHEN ELSE executes WHEN condition in specified order:

```
SELECT RegionID FROM WotifRegions WHERE SiteID = @SiteID AND 
    1 = CASE
          WHEN LocationName = @DepotCity THEN 1
          WHEN LocationName = @DepotName THEN 1
          WHEN LocationName = @LocationCity THEN 1
          WHEN LocationName = @LocationName THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END
```

Please let me know if am wrong and there is a better way.
FYI: Its a small table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also just do:

```
SELECT RegionID FROM WotifRegions WHERE SiteID = @SiteID AND 
     (LocationName = @DepotCity or
      LocationName = @DepotName or
      LocationName = @LocationCity or
      LocationName = @LocationName)
```

or if it's just the one field with several values:

```
SELECT RegionID FROM WotifRegions WHERE SiteID = @SiteID AND 
LocationName in (@DepotCity, @DepotName, @LocationCity, @LocationName)
```

if you actually mean also to sort data in that order, then something like this:

```
SELECT RegionID FROM WotifRegions 
WHERE SiteID = @SiteID AND 
LocationName in (@DepotCity, @DepotName, @LocationCity, @LocationName)
order by CASE
      WHEN LocationName = @DepotCity THEN 1
      WHEN LocationName = @DepotName THEN 2
      WHEN LocationName = @LocationCity THEN 3
      WHEN LocationName = @LocationName THEN 4
      ELSE 5 end
```

And if you need only the first, then add "top 1".

Comment: No, Sql Server doesn't guarantee execution of conditions as specified as far as I have read. Could you support your answer with a link mentioning it?

Comment: Comparing in specific order doesn't have any affect on the results. If you need data in order or to find the first row based on your priority, then you have to specify order by.

Comment: Yea, you are correct. Let me try your updated answer.